# Why can't I click the scrollable Textview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I made the fragment that has some Textviews.
2 Textviews are just Textviews, and others are scrollable Textviews.
I used the fragment on MainActivity.
I want whole area of the fragment is clickable. 
But if I click the area of scrollable Textviews's, it's not work.
It works when I click not scrollable Textviews only.
Why can't I click them?

Here are some part of my code.

**1. fragment.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_ins_time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/instruction_time_receipt"
    android:background="@color/MainTitleBackgroundColor"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_title_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_main_ins_time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" ->scroll
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/input02"
    android:textColor="@color/MainInputTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_ins_loc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/instruction_disaster_location"
    android:background="@color/MainTitleBackgroundColor"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_title_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_main_ins_loc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/input02"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/MainInputTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_text_size" />
```

**2. Fagment.java**

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ....

    tvTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main_ins_time);
    tvLocation = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main_ins_loc); 

    tvTime.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    tvLocation.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}
```

**3. main.xml**

```
...  <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_instruction_summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.85"
            android:name="(myPackageName).Fragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment" >
        </fragment> ....
```

**4. MainActivity.java**

```
findViewById(R.id.fragment_instruction_summary).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Please help me. 
I tried to put the fragment in a linearLayout and set click Listener to linearlayout, but it was the same result.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the second TextView in ScrollView? That way ScrollView is responsible for scroll and TextView for click events.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried and it didn't work also. @jelic98

Answer (score 0):

The Srolling works fine when used like layout. Try wrap your TextView's in another layout. Like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_ins_time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/instruction_time_receipt"
    android:background="@color/MainTitleBackgroundColor"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_title_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_ins_loc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/instruction_disaster_location"
    android:background="@color/MainTitleBackgroundColor"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_title_text_size"/>

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_height="your_preference"
    android:layout_width="your_preference">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="your_preference"
            android:layout_width="your_preference">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main_ins_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/input02"
            android:textColor="@color/MainInputTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main_ins_loc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.3"
            android:background="@drawable/input02"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/MainInputTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ll_instruction_summary_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And in your fragment:

```
ScrollView scrollView;

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ....

scrollView = (ScrollView) mView.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scrollView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  // do anything
 });

tvTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main_ins_time);
tvLocation = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_main_ins_loc);
tvTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     // do anything
});
tvLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     // do anything
});

tvTime.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
tvLocation.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to do something in MainActivity when I click that whole area of the fragment.  How can I....